# How to delete a folder I accidentally created in Win10 Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I accidentally created a "test" folder in the Win 10 Ubuntu directory, using the Win method instead of the command line. Then I deleted it, still using the Win method. The "test" folder can no longer be seen from the Win Explorer. However, it can still be seen from the Ubuntu terminal, though without access permission.

I tried to use `rmdir test` and `sudo rm -r test` but both could not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Just restart the Win10!